# Sample externally powered analog sensor with TelosB

Tags: msp430

This is a newbie question so forgive me for its simplicity

I have a FIGARO TGS 2602 Air Contaminant Sensor and would like to sample its analog output using TelosB which is powered by 3V-3.6V max voltage by batteries or USB.

The TGS sensor must be powered by a 5 volt min external power supply. 
Is there a way to sample its output (its output will never exceed 4 volts) with the TelosB without destroying the Telosb? That is, can I use a common ground for both the sensor and Telosb?

For example, at page 23, you can see that pin 9 is the analog ground:
http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kkolla/CSC714/datasheet.pdf
I can not power TGS 2602 with Analog VCC (pin 1) so I have to drive it with external source (5 volts min)

So my question again is, can I use pin 9 (analog ground) for common ground for Telosb and TGS 2602?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will *need* to connect the grounds together, and yes, it should be safe as long as there isn't a large ground potential difference between the two devices (only really happens between devices at remote sites).

The signal will need to be scaled down otherwise you risk blowing the ADC input.  A simple resistive divider should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your succinct answer. I guess I could use a zener diode regulator circuit too?. I will put an update on this with picts.

Comment: No, a zenner would clip the signal, not scale it. Any values greater than the zenner voltage would equal the zenner voltage, so you'd effectively lose all that data.